# Configuration to remote-site networking

Tags: routing, remote-access

Sorry if I miss some things or are unclear, I'm a bit noob in network.
We have this configuration of network:

[image: https://i.ibb.co/55YzBBK/image.png]

- I can't change local IP of remote site machine.
- I can't use IPV6 because of software that don't take it.
- I want to minimize configuration of customer servers/firewalls, ideally only open ports 80 and 443 to a specific site.
- I don't need to connect to multiple remote-site at the same time.
- Remote-site don't need to talk to each other.

So far i've looked at:

- Tailscale or similar (installed on windows machine): Works for 1 remote-site but needs 4over6 feature for multiple site and it does not work because I need to stay in IPV4.
- Anydesk or similar with TCP Tunneling (installed on Windows machine) : Works well but requires Technician to configure redirecting ports to all devices for each remote-site.

Am I missing some obvious way/software of doing that?

Thank you

Comment: We miss some detail, what problem you have that you want to resolve, and why both site are the same, is it somehow someone tried to do a cluster or such scenario ? For a solution, the technician could just do a VPN to the remote site they need to work on, why it wasnt tested ?

Comment: I Will try to explain the use case, we are 30 tech, and have ~50 remote-site. Each remote location is a standard setup, that's why they all have same IP. So we know that IP .21 is always "Device 1" but on a different customer.

I'm not familiar with VPN software/setup. How can it be configured in me case? right now I'm guessing a VPN server per Remote-site ? Then each tech will need to configure each VPN on their computer?

Comment: Why don't you use an RMM for this?

Comment: Right now we are accessing Computer with software like Anydesk, then accessing Device 1 with a software installed on "Windows HMI". We would like to access "device 1" from our computer. We can't install anything on "Device 1" (it's a PLC).

Comment: "Why don't you use an RMM for this?"

From what I understand, I could monitor/access Windows but I won't be able to talk directly to "Device 1" with RMM software.

Comment: @Maxime A RMM system would be the best, some allow you to have a probe that allow you to monitor the LAN, and even if a plc is there, you can remote to a system to take control of the said plc after. For your other question yes they need a VPN setup for all sites, but you can centralize a radius server so it would be a user on just one location that give access anywhere. The advantage is if your server fall down, in VPN you can remote to a iDRAC or such console., else like stated a RMM system would work good.

Comment: At my level of understanding, (very low), Tailscale is almost the same as a VPN setup right? I just don't understand how I can configure a VPN (or tailscale) so tech can choose which remote site they want to connect to. Is there an interface like Anydesk where I see all remote-site and click "connect" ?

Comment: I only used tailscale for a p2p connection (one computer to a other) I am not sure what business related environmental use would be